# Knockout Compose Binding

Tags: knockout.js

I have a main view in which I am using knockout compose binding to include another view.

```
 <div>
    <div data-bind="compose: {
                    model: 'viewmodels/sharedChart',
                    activate: true
                    }">

    </div>
</div>
```

The view that is included using knockout compose binding has a progress bar modal (twitter bootstrap).

```
<div class="modal hide fade" id="chartsLoading">  
     <div class="modal-header"> 
         Loading charts.....
     </div>
     <div class="modal-body">  
        <div class="progress progress-striped active page-progress-bar">
            <div class="bar" style="width:60%"></div>
     </div>
    </div>
```

```
vm.getCharts = function () {
        $('#chartsLoading').modal('show');
        };
```

I do not see any modal when the vm.getCharts function is called. Is it happening because the view with progress bar modal is loaded using compose binding ?

Answer (score 1):

Knockout compose binding is used to put down a different html section in that section. You have to specify the 'view' attribute

Ex:- view:'somepath/something.html'

This is mainly as far as I know is for code re-usability